I'm trying to change job industries and don't have the experience but do have the skills. What can I do?
I currently work in the hospitality industry (in sales and planning) and I am looking to leave the industry to work as an Executive Assistant or Office Manager but don't have that specific experience. How can I prove in my resume or cover letter that the skills I've learned in hospitality are transferrable to other industries?

This is way to broad, and will likely be closed.  If you need specific help refine your question.

Honestly you can't do anything about it besides praying that they pick you. They want 2 years of experience for internships nowadays.

If you have the skills you should be able to demonstrate these on your resume and point to them in your cover letter. Apply to a few jobs and see what happens.
If that doesn't work, you may have to try to gain some experience maybe through in internship or a lower paying entry level job.
A lot of this depends on your age and how far into your current career you are. Changing industries always comes with some loss of "applicable experience" and the further you are along, the more difficult this becomes to manage and communicate.

It may help to look for jobs where your current field is also applicable. Being able to act as a translator between two groups can be very valuable, if that is what an employer needs.
